# Define unbounded tuple in Flow

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Is it possible to define a tuple with repeating last item in Flow?

Example:

```
type Operator = '=' | '<' | '>';
type Value = string | number;

// this works...
type Expression = [Operator, Array<Value>];
const expr = ['=', [1, 2, 3]];

// ...but I would like to use it without nested array:
type Expression = [Operator, ...Value]; // this is not valid
const expr = ['=', 1, 2, 3];
```

Flow does typecheck the items in the tuple based on the index, so it is possible to define it like this:

```
type Expression = [Operator, Value, Value, Value, Value, Value];
const expr = ['=', 1, 2, 3];
```

But it will not typecheck items if the array is longer than the type definition.

Answer (score 0):

It does not support mixing a tuple and a list like this yet, but what it does support is 'tagged unions', which seems to be even better in this case! (Or do you want the amount of values to be dynamic even for the same operator?)

```
type Value = string | number;
type Expression =
  ['=', Value, Value, Value]
  | ['<', Value, Value]
  | ['>', Value]
```

With this, you can specify exactly how many values every operator accepts.

Comment: Yes, even for the same operator, number of values can vary. E.g. logical operators AND and OR:

    ['AND', ['<', 'age', 100], ['=', 'country', 'Canada'], ['>', 'foo', 200]]

Answer (score 0):

In your case, this should just work:

```
type Expression = [Operator, Value];
```

In flow tuples are always unbound, but type of "tail" is always a union of defined types, i. e. `Operator | Value`. Since `Operator` is subtype of `Value`, it's the same as `Value`.

Comment: No. Tail [can be anything](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgDy+ATgIYZwlgC8YA5DfWAD4MA8zb9AfPQNyZcBAGpkYAVwJ0AdhIC2AIzzU2AZwwkAljIDmg7PjABRAB44SeNWq1wZtMAG1iKilQA0YMZLwBdQagAxnYaYHjmJABcJhFWNnYOjoz0ngCMAEwAzGmpqZ4A3lBwcNEZmQC+nnIwMJ4AFACUtDxgACzp-kA).